# Issue downloading .XLSM file that has been uploaded via the Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I am facing:Upload .XLSM file via the Drive API and then try downloading from the user drive interface.  We have uploading an excel sheet to our newsprinter-sm drive with an .xlsm (macro) when we try to download google removes the .xlsm from the file name and the file is unusable unless you rename the file or select open with.

Google says: 
They've checked the screenshot and can see that the code that the uploaded file itself removed the file extension, however, because of declared mime-type or file header, Google Drive recognized it as Excel-File. The behavior that the file you then download is subsequently not correctly recognized by your computer is expected: Your operating system seems to rely on file extension instead of mime-type or file headers and does not have a default file-handler for this type, however "open with" will open the untampered file.

In short: The file is downloaded in the same state as it was uploaded, no modification of content or filename was made by the API or Google Drive.

Please note that the scope of API Support team is to ensure overall API functionality. The API and Google Drive are behaving as expected.

Our team doesn't offer support for specific coding errors through this support portal.

Please let me know what to do on this.